# Open source software for calculating terrain volumes for mining etc

Tags: open-source, calculator, land-surveying

I've been trying to find open source software for calculating the volume of material removed from a surveyed area. For example: In open pit mining where you take a series of way points or lidar point cloud data before mining begins, then periodically after material has been removed you take additional measurements to determine how much material was removed.

I have been looking in the Android app store, Google searches, etc. but have not found anything. There are professional solutions but I'm looking for open source alternatives that I could modify for my own use.

I can write my own app but am concerned about the accuracy of the few techniques I've thought about.

Comment: Not my area of expertise as to the tool for that – but it isn't that clear what OS it should run on. Looks like Android seems an option for you. Are you looking for a "mobile application" specifically? If so, could you [edit] your question and add the corresponding tag? If not, what other OS would match?